# How to make perl print all matches in command line?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to print all matches in command line like this:

```
perl -0777 -nle 'print "$1\n" if /ModelProxy\("([\w*.]+)"\);/g' test.txt
```

the `test.txt` like this:

```
var orderform = new ModelProxy("orderform.b2b.*");
var orderform2b = new ModelProxy("web.orderform_2b.*");
var o2oOrderform = new ModelProxy("orderform.o2o.*");
var logistics = new ModelProxy("supply.logistics.*");
var tyreurgent = new ModelProxy("o2o.tyreurgent.*");
var common = new ModelProxy("web.common.file.*");
var cartPipeData = load("pipe/cartPipeData");
var tsCartPipeData = load("pipe/tsCartPipeData").default;
```

I want is:

```
orderform.b2b.*
web.orderform_2b.*
orderform.o2o.*
supply.logistics.*
o2o.tyreurgent.*
web.common.file.*
```

but I got the first one:

```
orderform.b2b.*
```

Answer (score 5):

`if //g` makes no sense. You're looking for `while //g`.

```
perl -0777ne'print "$1\n" while /ModelProxy\("([\w*.]+)"\);/g' test.txt
```

Do you expect line breaks in the middle of your match? If not, there's no need to read the whole file into memory.

```
perl -nle'print for /ModelProxy\("([\w*.]+)"\);/g' test.txt
```